# Redirecting stdout to pipe and reading from it from a single process

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, dup

I'm porting a Linux program to a system which has **no fork()**, so everything runs in a single process. This program creates pipe, redirects stdout to pipe's input, forks, children calls printf and parent reads data from pipe. I removed fork, and tried to test it on Linux - the program is hanged on `read()` which waits for data on pipe. Here's a small reproducer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
const char in[7] = "qwerty";

int main ()
{
    int fds[2], stdout_sav;
    char str[8] = {0};
    pipe(fds);
    if ((stdout_sav = dup(1)) < 0) return 1;  // save stdout
    if (dup2(fds[1], 1) < 0) return 2;   // stdout -> pipe
    close(fds[1]);

    if (printf(in) <= 0) return 3;
    //fsync(1);        // behavior does not change if I add a fsync here
    read(fds[0], str, sizeof(in));    // HERE: read waits for data
    close(fds[0]);
    if (dup2(stdout_sav, 1) < 0) return 4;   // restore stdout
    close(stdout_sav);

    printf("Received %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

As it does not work on Linux, I suppose there is wrong logic in the code, but I don't see any problems with it.

I had an idea that a single process won't write to pipe if there are no readers, however, this is not true as the following code works OK:

```
    pipe(fds);
    write(fds[1], in, sizeof(in));
    close(fds[1]);
    read(fds[0], str, sizeof(in));
    close(fds[0]);
    printf("Received %s\n", str);
```

Comment: What is the *actual* program doing? Can it be ported to use the native process-creation functions of the target you're porting to? What is the target you're porting to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten that when connected to a pipe `stdout` is *fully* buffered.

You need to explicitly flush `stdout` for the data to actually be written to the pipe. Since the data isn't flushed, there's nothing in the pipe to be read, and the `read` call blocks.

So after the `printf` call you need `fflush(stdout)`.